# How do I access a variable outside of it's Function?

Tags: flutter, function, properties, flutter-layout, global-variables

```
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}


void getLocation() async {
 Location locs = Location();
 List<double> list = await locs.getCurrentLocation();
print(list[1]);
}

void getData() async {
 http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
   'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=$appId'));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
String data = response.body;

var longitude = jsonDecode(data)['coord']['lon'];
var description = jsonDecode(data)['weather'][0]['description'];
print(longitude);
print(description);
} else {
print(response.statusCode);
}
}

 class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 getData();
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
      child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          },
          child: const Text('Get Location'))),
);
  }
 }
```

I wish to access the property list which is inside the getLocation() function. But If I refer to other StackOverflow Solutions, everyone has been assigning something to the variable like this one

```
        import 'package:clima/constants.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';
    
    class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
    }
    
    double lattitude;
    double longitude;
    
    void getLocation() async {
      Location locs = Location();
      List<double> list = await locs.getCurrentLocation();
      var lattitute = list[0];
      var longitude = list[1];
    }
    
    void getData() async {
      http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lattitude&lon=$longitude&appid=$appId'));
    
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
    
        var longitude = jsonDecode(data)['coord']['lon'];
        var description = jsonDecode(data)['weather'][0]['description'];
        print(longitude);
        print(description);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }
    
    class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        getData();
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    getLocation();
                  },
                  child: const Text('Get Location'))),
        );
      }
    }
```

But if I do that, the double has not been initialized and if I try adding the late keyword, I get a Late Initialization error. Can you help me??

Answer (score 0):

use the second code you posted,
calling a function that does a network request inside the build function is a bad thing! because whenever you call `setState((){})` that function will be called again
change your function from `void getLocation() async` to `Future getLocation() async` to you can wait for it till finish it's job
inside your `ElevatedButton.onPressed` change the code to:

```
void getLocation() async {
  Location locs = Location();
  List<double> list = await locs.getCurrentLocation();
  var lattitute = list[0]; // -> remove var
  var longitude = list[1]; // -> remove var
}

onPressed: () async {
    await getLocation();
    getData();
},
```

it's important to remove `getData` function from the `build` method

Comment: But If I do that,the double lattitude; and the double longitude; will not be initialized so how can I use them inside my API link?

Comment: I updated my answer, did not notice that `vars` inside your `getLocation` method, remove them from your method and it will work, before there is an `await` before hitting your API request